# Method aliasing in class with Groovy

Tags: groovy

I'm going to internationalize groovy API abit.

For final class (e.g. String)

```
String.metaClass.вСтроку = {-> this.toString() }
```

However, this will create additional closure. Isn't there any way to just `alias` method with another method?

Something like this:

```
String.metaClass.вСтроку = String.metaClass.&toString
```

Comment: What is the problem of creating an additional closure?

Comment: Additional java.class will be created. This is not optimal if I'm going to internationalize all groovy API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use @Category transform like this

```
@Category(String) class StringInternationalization {
    String вСтроку() {
        this.toString()
    }

    int длина() {
        this.length()
    }
}

class ApplyMixin {
    static {
        String.mixin(StringInternationalization)
        final helloString = "Привет мир!"
        println helloString.вСтроку()
        assert helloString.длина() == helloString.length()
    }
}

new Main()
```

This will create 1 Category class for each localised class and one class to apply all mixin transformations(to register all methods.) Also should be faster, then individual closures.

More reading here: http://groovy.codehaus.org/Category+and+Mixin+transformations

Comment: Thanks. I'll analyze proposed apporach and will be back to you.

Comment: +1. Extensions are a good way to go, also, since they don't need the `static { }` block